# Read File Element wise

Tags: c, linux, file-io

i want to read text file containing the data of 4X4 matrix each element is separated by a space and it is divided into 4 rows which represent the matrix. it is in Following form

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

now i came across the code that

```
 static const char filename[] = "file.txt";
   FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
   if ( file != NULL )
   {
      char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */

      while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
      {
         fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
      }
      fclose ( file );
   }
   else
   {
      perror ( filename ); /* why didn't the file open? */
   }
   return 0;
```

which reads the file but i want to know that how to read them element wise so that i can store them in 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fscanf to the rescue:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!file)
        perror("Can't open input");

    int matrix[4][4] = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    };

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        int n = fscanf(file, "%i %i %i %i", &matrix[i][0], 
                &matrix[i][1],
                &matrix[i][2],
                &matrix[i][3]);
        if (n != 4) {
            if (errno != 0)
                perror("scanf");
            else 
                fprintf(stderr, "No matching characters\n");
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        printf("%i %i %i %i\n", matrix[i][0], 
                matrix[i][1],
                matrix[i][2],
                matrix[i][3]);
}
```

Of course you need to make the code more generic

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE* file;

  int array[4][4];

  int y;
  int x;

  file = fopen("matrix.txt","r");
  for(y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      fscanf(file, "%d", &(array[x][y]));
    }
    fscanf(file, "\n");
  }
  fclose (file);
  for(y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      printf("%d ", array[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: in production code you should check the return value of `fopen` (it might be `NULL`), and the return value of `fscanf` (did it read the expected amount of elements?).

Answer (score 2):

Keep a line and column count. Change the inside of the while loop

```
      line = 0;
      column = 0;
      while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
      {
         // fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */

         <FOR EVERY VALUE IN LINE>
         {

             matrix[line][column] = <VALUE>;
             column++;
             if (column == 4) {
                 column = 0;
                 line++;
             }

         }

      }
```

As for the <FOR EVERY VALUE IN LINE> `strtok()` comes to mind -- or you could use the `is*` functions declared in `<ctype.h>`.

If you absolutely trust the input, `sscanf()` is a good option too.